# put labels to ggplot2 graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add labels to **ggplot2** graphs that have many points and lines using `geom_line`. Since the graph has way too many data points and linear lines, it looks very cluttered.

I would like to add lables to the linear lines so that end user will definetely know what lines belongs to what server etc.

my data frame looks like this

```
> z
Hostname    Memory  Date
ServerA         50  2012-01-01 01:00:00
ServerB         30  2012-01-01 01:00:00
ServerC         30  2012-01-01 01:00:00
ServerD         20  2012-01-01 01:00:00
ServerE         80  2012-01-01 01:00:00

ServerA         20  2012-01-02 01:00:00
ServerB         10  2012-01-02 01:00:00
ServerC         5   2012-01-02 01:00:00
ServerD         39  2012-01-02 01:00:00
ServerE         50  2012-01-02 01:00:00



p <- ggplot(z, aes(x=Date, y=Memory, colour=Hostname, size=0.1)) + 
        geom_point(size=0.1) + theme_bw

() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, size = 1) + 
         theme_bw() + geom_point(size=0.2)
```

I tried using `direct.label(p, "last.points")` or `first.points`, but it is still not clear enough. And when I do last.points, labels are being chopped off.

Is it possible to put a lable on the `lm` line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change some setting in your original script: I added group=Hostname, and removed size=0.1 from the first row, in the next row you can customise the geom_point (i changed its shape to x), then  for geom_smooth function you should use: aes(group = Hostname), and at last the direct.label() works fine.

```
library(ggplot2)  
library(directlabels)  
myplot<-ggplot(z, aes(x=Date, y=Memory, group=Hostname, colour=Hostname))+  
geom_point(size=3, shape=4) +  
geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(group = Hostname), se=FALSE, size=1)  
myplot<- direct.label(myplot, "last.points")
```

As far as i know there is no prewritten method for this, you should write your own "positioning method", you can try something like this, where "slope" is the slope of the lm curve. (as you can see it's not yet dynamic)

```
slope<-c(-30,-20, 60, 50, -40)  
label.above <- list("first.points", rot = slope, hjust = -0.5, vjust = -0.5)  
direct.label(myplot, label.above)
```

where z is:

```
z<-structure(list(Hostname = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("ServerA", "ServerB", "ServerC", "ServerD", "ServerE"), class = "factor"), Memory = c(50L, 30L, 30L, 20L, 80L, 20L, 10L, 5L, 39L, 50L), Date = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("  2012-01-02 01:00:00", " 2012-01-01 01:00:00", " 2012-01-02 01:00:00"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Hostname", "Memory", "Date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```